# While loop test alternative

Tags: php, coding-style

I have some really ugly code and I need help to clean it up. I'm sure there must be a better way.
I have a $_POST variable with entries start_doy0, start_doy1, start_doy2 etc.

The later entries my not be filled and I need to find up to what doy they are filled.
I cant start with $completed_index = -1 because there is no start_doy-1.

```
#Assume at least one line full, index 0.
$completed_index = 0;
 while (!empty($_POST['start_doy'.$completed_index]))
 {
 $completed_index++;
 }

# $_POST['start_doy'.$completed_index] was empty, decrement $completed_index.
$completed_index--;
```

Thnks,
Matt

Comment: if at least index 0 exists, you can start from 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Your `<form>` should contain `<input name="start_doy[]">` fields, so that you can work with arrays.

Comment: If the user completes start_doy0, start_doy2, and start_doy3 (but **not** start_doy1), your while loop will stop before it gets to start_doy2 and start_doy3 - so you could miss stuff. I don't know if that's relevant or not... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions, depending on how much you can change the calling code, and whether the start_doy fields are guaranteed to be filled in order (ie, user can't fill in start_doy9, but not start_doy2).

Option 1: Change your HTML so that the form fields are submitted with array syntax, like this:

```
One: <input type="text" name="start_doy[]"/><br/>
Two: <input type="text" name="start_doy[]"/><br/>
```

On the PHP side, this will be converted to an array, so your processing could be something like this:

```
<?php

$completed_indexes = array();

if(isset($_POST['start_doy']))
{
    foreach($_POST['start_doy'] as $key => $start_doy)
    {
        if(false == empty($start_doy))
            $completed_indexes[] = $key;
    }
}

echo count($completed_indexes);

?>
```

Option 2: Or if you can't change the HTML, or prefer this solution, you could iterate the array and check the key matches what you want:

```
<?php

$completed_indexes = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if(substr($key,0,9) == "start_doy" && false == empty($value))
        $completed_indexes[] = $key;
}

echo count($completed_indexes);

?>
```

Comment: Option 1 would be always preferable, but why are testing each `$_POST['start_doy']` variable of value? That's unnecessary. You can ealesy just check for it's size to find out how many are there `sizeof($_POST['start_doy'])`. Because, if it's posted, it's supposed to be there ;)

Comment: @DainisAbols - The reason for the test inside the foreach is to check if the value is empty. The OP used empty() - so I assumed there could be start_doy0 -> start_doy10, but perhaps only start_doy0 -> start_doy4 entered by the user.

Comment: Well... if you want to show count of only set variables, you can also do it like this: `echo array_sum(array_count_values($_POST['start_doy']))-(($res=array_count_values($_POST['start_doy']))?$res['']:0);`

Comment: Yeah, except that's entirely unreadable code - 1 line != 1337. The OP might want to use the values too, the count was just an example ;)

Comment: I changed the HTML - a lot neater all round!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove some some brackets and change it to `isset`, but other then that, the code looks pretty clean to me:

```
$completed_index = 0; # assume at least one line full, index 0.
while(isset($_POST['start_doy'.$completed_index])) $completed_index++;
$completed_index--; # $_POST['start_doy'.$completed_index] was empty, decrement $completed_index.
```

Comment: It's the $completed_index-- that is annoying me!

Comment: Well ... rename it to `$ci` or something like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "count" function like this :

```
$completed_index = count($_POST);
```

and then remove the other elements. for example if you have two other element do this :

```
$completed_index -=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Just use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Algo

```
$clean_post = array_filter( $_POST );
```

then you can simply use all post values

```
foreach ($clean_post as $doy => $value) {
...
}
```

only the non-empty values will remain in `$clean_post` (and this is done faster in C by a PHP function).

--

In you current algo:

- You may want to check for `0` as well

Algo

```
 $completed_index = -1;
 do {
   $completed_index++;
 } while ( ! empty($_POST['start_doy' . $completed_index]));
```

result: `$completed_index` is the number of completed indexes (last index is `$completed_index-1` or `-1` if there is none)